# asp.net C# database table column to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have an asp.net project done in C# (my C# syntax is very rusty) and am using the built in database it creates with the project. I've created a table called aspnet_Tutorials that (for now) stores two columns of user submitted data: TutorialName and TutorialContent. Very simple, it's a learning project.

What I need to do is create a list from the first column of aspnet_Tutorials to use it to create a "directory" of the tutorials on a page. The part I'm having trouble with, mostly syntactically, is connecting to and iterating over the column to get the values into a list. Could anyone provide a straight forward example of this? And possibly explain what's going on in the code.

```
public class TutorialsDirDAL
    {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        public List<string> DisplayTutorials() //parameters? String qry?
        {
           //query the database table, foreach loop over the data, place it into a list?
        }
    }
```

I know how to write simple sql queries. But I've seen a couple different set ups for this in my Googling spree. I currently have the following for a query, feel free to pick it apart or offer a better solution than using a query.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ASPNET_TUTORIALS (TutorialTitle)"
                + "VALUES (@tutorialTitle)";
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think this question is a bit *too* basic. Basic in the sense, that a Google search would give a very comprehensive tutorial. It's like asking, how to declare an `int` variable in C#. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: It seems you are learning... Why not learn with a book? having looks to msdn... you can't expect people to write code for you : you would learn nothing.

Comment: I don't think you know how to write any SQL. Start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ebad86's answer is acceptable but since you are obviously learning I think introducing OO principals muddy the water with what you are trying to learn at this point.

Here is a basic method:

```
private void GetData()
{
   //The object that will physically connect to the database
   using(SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("<your connection string>")
   {
            //The SQL you want to execute
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASPNET_TUTORIALS");
           //Open the connection to the database
           cnx.Open();
           //execute your command
           using (IDataReader dataReader = cnx.ExecuteReader(cmd))
           {
             //Loop through your results
             while(dataReader.Read())
             {
                //do whatever to the data
                ListItem item = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(dataReader["TutorialName"])); 
                lst.Items.Add(item);
             }
           }
   }
}
```

This is all very straightforward.  The part you are most interested in is the while loop though.  The loop will go through all of the returned records and you can do whatever you need to do with them.  In my example I have assumed that there is a ListBox named 'lst' and I am simply adding ListItems to it that will have the name of whatever 'TutorialName' is.  You can make literally do whatever you need to do with the data at this point.  To fit your example (returning a List) you would do this:

```
private List<string> GetData()
{
   List<string> lst = new List<string>();
   //The object that will physically connect to the database
   using(SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("<your connection string>")
   {
            //The SQL you want to execute
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASPNET_TUTORIALS");
           //Open the connection to the database
           cnx.Open();
           //execute your command
           using (IDataReader dataReader = cnx.ExecuteReader(cmd))
           {
             //Loop through your results
             while(dataReader.Read())
             {
                lst.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["TutorialName"]));
             }
           }
   }
   return lst;
}
```

Please respond if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for putting up this example and explaining it. I made a few changes: put the connection string in the class TutorialsDirDal and added ', cnx' after the sql query so that the ExecuteReader would work properly. I'm very much interested in learning a more Object Oriented approach, so I am re-getting a crash course in how to properly institute an OO design. I'm already implementing the separation of business logic layer and data access layer, which I'm still coming to understand. Anyway, thank you for the help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have the cnx.ExecuteReader() option when I try to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can fetch using data reader and map to the object. I can give you some rough code, which could be like this:

```
            using (IDataReader objDataReader = objDB.ExecuteReader(objCMD))
            {
                while (objDataReader.Read())
                {
                    DataBaseObject obj = new DataBaseObject();
                    obj = MapObjectToList(objDataReader);
                    ObjectList.Add(obj);

                }
                objDataReader.Dispose();
            }
```

// Mapping Function can be called somewhat like this:

```
private DataBaseObject MapObjectToList(IDataReader objDataReader)
{
    DataBaseObject obj = new DataBaseObject();
    obj.Prop1Name = base.GetDataValue<string>(objDataReader, "Column1Name");
    obj.Prop2Name = base.GetDataValue<string>(objDataReader, "Column2Name");
    return obj;
}
```

But this is just a rough idea how I would do it.

Comment: This was a little harder to understand, at first. After going over abszero's example I was able to better understand this. I'll eventually get around to trying this sample and see how it works differently. Thank you for the help.